# Best practise for repositioning absolutely positioned elements on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have many elements positioned absolutely in my page. What is the best practice method to re-adjust its position on window resize(all of them)?

Comment: I think people are going to need more information, as there are quite a number of different ways in which elements might be absolutely positioned.

Comment: different ways? i thought position : absolute with a top & left would position them absolute

Comment: @Ajay well yes; that's not what I meant :-)  I meant that it really depends on what your pages look like. Sometimes, the way that things are positioned - even with "position: absolute" - is that they will resize along with the window. Sometimes it does not make sense for them to change when the window resizes. It all depends on the design.

Comment: @ajax: Not only `left` and `top`. You can use `right` and `bottom` instead, which may minimize your need to do this with JavaScript.

Comment: how can right and bottom achieve this? 
P.S : who's ajax by the way ^o)

Comment: @Ajay: (LOL Sorry, you can guess why I'm used to typing that.) See my answer for more about the role of `right` and `bottom` in repositioning elements on resize. Basically, if you want an element absolutely positioned and anchored right (say, 10px from the right edge), you can do that purely with CSS, no JavaScript required.

Comment: @Ajay: I've added an example of the use of `right` and `bottom`, to illustrate my point.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest the best practise is to do this with CSS and avoid doing it with JavaScript if you possibly can. So avoid absolute positioning when you can, and when positioning absolutely use percentages rather than pixel values where possible, use `right` rather than `left` when positioning elements you want anchored right, use `bottom` rather than `top` when positioning elements you want anchored to the bottom, etc., etc. E.g.: Let the browser handle it for you.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Resize Demo Page</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#anchorRight {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#anchorBottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left:  20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#anchorBoth {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Look, Ma, no JavaScript required.</p>
<div id='anchorRight'>Anchor right, 20% from top</div>
<div id='anchorBottom'>Anchor bottom, 20% from left</div>
<div id='anchorBoth'>Anchor bottom and right</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A pure CSS solution may not always be possible. When doing it with JavaScript, you'll have to watch not only for window resize events but also text resize, which is more of a pain (Google's [Closure library](http://code.google.com/closure/library/) includes utilities for doing that). Also be sure to build-in [hysteresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis) to avoid repositioning your elements too frequently during the actual resize operation. (An easy way to do that is to respond to a resize by setting a function to be called by `setTimeout` a quarter second later and remembering the timer handle; if you get another resize event before the function is called, cancel the earlier timer and set a new one. You can set a max number of times you defer the resize before you go ahead [to show interim updates], but since moving these things with JavaScript may be a bit slow, you don't want to do it on *every* interim event you get during the operation.)

Comment: +1: I'd only caution that the developer should check whether a percentage distance from the edges of the viewport is what he really wants.

Comment: @Robusto: Oh, absolutely. I only used percentages in the example to demonstrate that one *can*. That may sully the point...

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do the following:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    jQuery('#ContainerDiv').html( jQuery('#ContainerDiv').html() );
});
```

Although it's probably not best practice.